# Is $\phi(z)$ is onto ? choose the correct statement ..

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

My attempts : By mobius Transformation Formula  $f(z) = \frac {az+b}{cz+ d}$ now 
 here  i take $a = c= 1$ as $|\frac{a}{c}|= 1$  , $f(z) = \frac{a}{c} \frac{(z+ \frac{b}{a})} {(z+ \frac{d}{c})}$ we can write  $\frac {a}{c} = e^{i\theta}$ for some $\theta$  $\in \mathbb{R} $ ,,,,$f(z) = e^{i\theta} (\frac{ z - \beta }{ z-\alpha} )$ as $ -1 \le \frac {b}{ d} \le 1$ now  i know  that $\phi (z) = \frac{1+z}{1-z}  < 1$

now  by open mapping theorem,,,option 3  is corrects..

is its correct...??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not correct. Note that$$\varphi(z)=-1\iff1+z=-1+z\iff-1=1$$and therefore $-1$ does not belong to the range of $\varphi$.

On the other hand, the fourth option is correct because, if $w\neq-1$,$$\varphi(z)=w\iff z=\frac{w-1}{w+1}.$$

Comment: thanks u @ Jose carlos sir ..then  which one is correct ??? can u  elaborate the correct answer ?

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: yes  i got  its  @ Jose  sir.....one more  last doubts    can u   tell me  why option 1 is not correct ??

Comment: Because, for instance, $\varphi(0)=1$.

Comment: thanks  u i gots    its  @ jose sir

Comment: yes  i agree,,,,,i gots  it  thanks  u  @jose sir